# Web-scraping: GET request returns a string - how can I read/process it in R?

Tags: javascript, r, http, web-scraping, get

I'm sending a GET request to an governmental page in India with the following URL:
https://pmfby.gov.in/landingPage/districtState?stateID=2F3DE245-46E6-4C4D-9297-C0B23C803B15&sssyID=02012223

What this basically does on their webpage (https://pmfby.gov.in/ -> "Insurance Premium Calculator") is returning all districts for a specific state selected (with JavaScript).

I used the following R code to reproduce this:

```
content(httr::GET("https://pmfby.gov.in/landingPage/districtState?stateID=2F3DE245-46E6-4C4D-9297-C0B23C803B15&sssyID=02012223"))
```

I somehow expected to get a HTML or JSON structured return with a list of those districts. What I actually get back however is a string that starts with "09f2ba53495a95c8d6189182d996252553a088b548d4f3c7caf1e195ff....".

I don't even know what format this is and I'm unable to convert/process this is R.
Is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: Why don't you scrape it using another method?

Comment: If I follow the link in my web browser, I see exactly the described string (which appears to be a hexadecimal number). Your code seems to be working fine. You seem to be trying to access something that isn't a proper API.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! @Anisa: Because I don't know any other :(

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply!  @Roland: When using their webpage, their form is properly filled with several district names as expected. I used devtools in chrome to see what url their using as GET request (which is the one mentioned above) and this only returns this hexadecimal number. Maybe I'm missing part of the request url? I'm really a newbie on this..

Comment: You should contact them and inquire if they offer / are willing to offer a proper API. Or maybe they could provide the actual dataset to you.

Comment: @Roland Tried to do this, but no response.

Comment: If the goal is to have just list of districts for state, I would use other source, like `geodata::gadm(country = "IND", level = 2, path = "data")` or fetch the boundary data from Openstreetmap ({osmdata} package). If you would run their calculator, then consider `rvest::LiveHTML()` function or {chromote} package.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all the advice. It's the underlying data that is of interest to me which is filled with javascript and which I tried to grab it via GET request. However, it does not seem to be possible that easily.

Grzegorz's advise to use `rvest::LiveHTML()` brought me on the right track. However I'm using RSelenium together with xpath to fill the form and grab the data once completed. The key to success was basically this line:

`remoteDriver$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"][1]/div/select')$sendKeysToElement(list("Rabi"))$clickElement()`

Cheers, NoAlibi